# Removing a specific row from a tableview based on index received through NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have got two view controllers.

First view controller has got a table view.
when the user clicks a cell in a tableview of first view controller, he will be guided to second view controller.

when the user returns back again to the first view controller, the table view cell which he clicked previously has to be removed from the table view

Following is my code

```
-(void)reloadOnAction:(NSNotification *)notis{


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    NSDictionary *dict = notis.userInfo;
    int index_Id = [[dict objectForKey:@"post_notification"] intValue];
    if ([_statNameArray count] != 0){
        [_statNameArray removeObjectAtIndex:index_Id];
    }
    [_tblView reloadData];
});}
```

the index_Id contains the element that has to removed.
Though i Have reloaded the table view after altering the array, the changes are not being reflected in the ui. How can i sort this out?

Following is my numberOfRowsInSection method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.statNameArray count];
}
```

Comment: Why do you create a whole new `UITableViewController` object?

Comment: no need of this UITableViewController`

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: the value is removed from _statNameArray when i call `[_statNameArray removeObjectAtIndex:index_Id];` but the `[_tblView reloadData]` is not reflecting the changes hence the contents remains the same

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the code inside `dispatch_async` runs? Put a log message or a breakpoint to see. Also, can you show us your `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` implementation?

Comment: I have put up my numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: dispatch_async runs  but the tableview is not getting reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store rows what must be removed in Array and remove this rows in viewWillAppear method.

It would be something like this:

```
@interface TableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedIndex;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *statNameArray;
@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self.statNameArray count] != 0){
        [self.statNameArray removeObjectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)reloadOnAction:(NSNotification *)notis{
    NSDictionary *dict = notis.userInfo;
    self.selectedIndex = [[dict objectForKey:@"post_notification"] intValue];
}
```

Comment: Could you check if code inside `if ([self.statNameArray count] != 0){ ... }` has been executed?

Comment: but every time the numberOfRowsInSection has got the same number of count

Answer (score 0):

When you return to the class responsible for the first view controller, make sure you call viewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [self.tableView reloadData]; // to reload selected cell
}
```